# How to extract row data from HTML table and convert to text for Selenium and c#

Tags: c#, selenium

I am new to selenium and c#,then I encountered an HTML table which is below:

```
<table class="datatable" id="MainContent">
   <tr class = "headerRow">
     <tr class = "datatable">
      <td class="hiddenColumn">1</td>
      <td style="width:20%;">Test 1</td>
     <tr class = "altrow">
      <td class="hiddenColumn">2</td>
      <td style="width:20%;">Test 2</td>
</table>
```

I tried this:

```
    string searchResult = DriverContext.Driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("#MainContent tr[class='datatable'], tr[class='altrow']")).ToString();
Console.WriteLine(searchResult.ToString());
```

I am unable to display the contents of datatable and altrow in text. What is the best approach for this, as I would also want to compare the text values to our database

Comment: Is provided HTMLof  table structure is correct?? Provide with closing tag as well?? You table looks incorrect?? And Do you want to get each column text separately in the loop, or want to all combination in one call??

Comment: i'd like to get each column text separately in the loop to compare the values to the database. Am I going on the right path?

Comment: I made use of the Entity Framework and it answered my question. Thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `FindElements()` method returns a collection of WebElements. Then you can access text of each element by the property `Text`.
So the code should be like this:

```
var elements = DriverContext.Driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("#MainContent tr.datatable,#MainContent tr.altrow")).ToList();
elements.ForEach(e => Console.WriteLine(e.Text));
```